# No pipe found with name '' when piping a value in a method call inside of a template

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to send a value through a pipe before I pass it onto the method as a parameter like this:

`<test (valueChange)="onValChange($event | testPipe)"></test>`

However, this casues an error:

`No pipe found with name ''.`

The pipe and components are all declared in the same module, see this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rngpen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Can we pipe values like this? If so, how?

The error can be avoided by simply passing the value unpiped and transforming the value inside the method, but I would like to do this inside of the template explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, why do you want to take this approach ?

Comment: pipes are meant for display. You can reuse the transform in the component e.g. [digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-pipes-in-component-class) but ask yourself if that's the kind of dependency you want. Ideally components are dumb as possible

Comment: @MGX It would make my shared component easier to use in multiple places where I expect the output to be a `string` or a `number`, depending on where I use it. I've tried fiddling with it and came to the conclusion that it may not be possible, so I gave it a whirl asking here.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I'm aware of the workarounds and I agree, however the error message confused me since I am using the pipe the same everywhere else and it works fine.

Comment: @Cuzy you can simply put your logic into the component, you don't need to write a pipe for that, it just seems like an extra step and some unwanted logic to me